# How to access HTML within custom tags in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created a custom directive.

```
<foo>
</foo>
```

Is there any way to access html within these tags ? For example

```
<foo>
<div>
....
</div>
</foo>
```

I want to access this div in my JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a ngTransclude

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

```
.directive('foo', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
  };
```

Comment: How can I get that div in my JS so that I can append that div to another directive?

Comment: Can you describe whole use case what you need?

Comment: I want that div as an attribute in my controller so that I can render it in my another view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the data-attr syntax?

```
<div data-foo>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And from the comments: You can inject `$element` and access or copy it's contents.

Comment: using $element is bad idea.

Comment: I don't see why it is a bad idea, concerning the question you have asked. Please refine your question and elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

1.Define the directive with the template 
2.by id attribute u can append set of html tags from .js file